# MediaCodec IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I have a problem with decoding mp3 file using `MediaCodec`. Logcat says the problem is with the line `codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId, 0, data.length, 0, 0)` but it looks fair to me.

Code:

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 ) {

        try {
            codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("audio/mpeg");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        codec.setCallback(new MediaCodec.Callback() {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onInputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int inputBufferId) {
                ByteBuffer inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(inputBufferId);

                inputBuffer.wrap(data);
                codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId, 0, data.length, 0, 0);  // java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

            }
        }
 }
```

logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: pl.test.projectx, PID: 18252

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

at android.media.MediaCodec.native_queueInputBuffer(Native Method)

at android.media.MediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2334)

at pl.test.projectx.Decoder$2.onInputBufferAvailable(Decoder.java:107)

at android.media.MediaCodec$EventHandler.handleCallback(MediaCodec.java:1663)

at android.media.MediaCodec$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaCodec.java:1621)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: try using MediaCodec.createByCodecName(). Even i faced this issue and i solved it using the above method. i noticed in most of mediatek devices createDecoderByType doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Gautam I've just checked it. Changed `MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("audio/mpeg")` for `MediaCodec.createByCodecName("OMX.google.mp3.decoder")` but the effect is unfortunately the same. Thanks for try anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `data` here - the whole mp3 file? You need to split it into individual packets (e.g. using `MediaExtractor`)

Then when feeding the data into the input buffer, `inputBuffer.wrap(data);` doesn't do what you want. `wrap` is actually a static method that creates a new `ByteBuffer`. What you want is `inputBuffer.clear(); inputBuffer.put(data);`.

Comment: Yes, `data` was whole mp3 file. What do you mean by writing "split into invidual packets"? Packets mean samples, frames or something else?

Comment: Thank you. I have another problem now but this is for another question :)